# @html.Action pass value from an input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to ask if how would it be possible to pass the value from the input field to the third parameter of @Html.Action in order to be accessed to the controller method. Here is my code:

In my view:
Here is the script that passes the id to the input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".desktop_id", function () {
        var deskId = $(this).data('id');
        $(".modal-body #idd").val(deskId);
    });
</script>
```

Here is the modal to show the partial view of the action

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.desktop_info_id" title="Add this item" class="desktop_id" href="#myModal1"><i title="Actions" class="fa fa-th"></i></a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">Actions</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" name="idd" id="idd" value=""/>
                @Html.Action("Transaction", "Desktop", new {id=---need to be field---})
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button"class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would it be possible that the @Html.Action("Transaction", "Desktop", new {id=---need to be filled---}) third paraameter can access the id value the same from the input field so that I can pass it to the controller? Thanks.

Comment: @Grundy if u edited - do it well pls. Code unreadable till now.

Comment: @Legendary, now it better? :-)

Comment: Is this sharepoint?  Because @Html means nothing in either javascript or jQuery.

Comment: @JohnGreen it ASP.Net MVC, razor template

Comment: `@Html.Action("Transaction", "Desktop", new {id=---need to be field---})` render on server side, so you can't pass params to this action from client

Comment: but you can do ajax query to this action and insert result

Comment: I would like to know if how would it be possible that instead of using the input's id to contain the id, how can i pass the desktop id to the@Html.Action as a "new" parameter instead?

Comment: if you pass inside script this value `data-id="@item.desktop_info_id"` why you not use it directly like: `@Html.Action("Transaction", "Desktop", new {id=item.desktop_info_id})`? But possibly you have a few `<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.desktop_info_id" class="desktop_id"... >`

Comment: @Grundy, If I directly passed it to Html.Action, the id is the same of all the list displayed because I'm using modal here. It seems like it's only the first id being processed by the action.

Comment: @user4656677 can you show code where you get `@item`? if you have `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1"` inside some foreach, then on client side you have a few div with same 'id', and when you try get this modal by id, you get first. Also can you show how you use this modal?

Comment: consider that the modal is inside a foreach loop:

foreach(var item in Model){

-->code above here

}

that's why i'm able to get the @item id

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect to your action directly from your jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".desktop_id", function () {
        var deskId = $(this).data('id');
        var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Transaction", "Desktop", new { id = "_id" }))';
        url = url.replace("_id", deskId);
        window.location(url);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @vortex, thanks for the answer but the "_id" does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you need. your modal depends on id so you can use it directly like

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.desktop_info_id" title="Add this item" class="desktop_id" href="#@item.desktop_info_id"><i title="Actions" class="fa fa-th"></i></a>
```

**NOTE**: here in `href="#@item.desktop_info_id"` used dynamic id

Also set same id for modal: `id="@item.desktop_info_id"`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="@item.desktop_info_id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel1">Actions</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" name="idd" id="idd" value=""/>
                @Html.Action("Transaction", "Desktop", new {id=item.desktop_info_id})
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button"class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
Here fiddle with sample, and all seems work: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/23Up3l)

Comment: Yes that's it. But everytime I clicked on the modal, the id in the action is the same. Only the first id of the list has been rendered. Whenever I clicked on the next one, still same id is shown.

Comment: @user4656677 do you change to `<div class="modal fade" id="@item.desktop_info_id"` and `<a ... href="#@item.desktop_info_id"`?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I don't get what you mean @Grundy.

Comment: the id is okay in <a href> part, but the modal body where the Html.Action is rendered, the same action is shown inspite of different id. Suppose to be, there are different views to be shown depending on the id of the action.

Comment: @user4656677 so possibly error in `"Transaction", "Desktop"`? Are you sure that this action return different result depends on `id` parameter? Can you provide code for this action in your OP?

Comment: I have been using this action without using modal. And it works well. But now that I embedded it to modal, to make it more nice, it doesn't work like it was used to. Is there something to do with the modal's id to the modal body's id?

Comment: @user4656677 i create a simplest app, and all works - modal shows with different content depends on id. Are you sure that change modal id to? You need change _href_ for `a` tag and _id_ for modal

Comment: @user4656677 i also add link to fiddle in answer, check it